# VBA Vlookup a filename

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to include a `Dim` in a Vlookup.

```
Dim filename As String
filename = Format(DateAdd("d", -6, Now()), "mm-dd-yy")
filename = "NSC " & filename & ".xlsm"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate

        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & filename & "]" & ws & "'!R8C4:R500C6,3,FALSE)"
Next
```

My error comes at **filename** in the vlookup.  I knew it would cause issues but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Filename will look something like "NSC 06-03-15.xlsm" and I cannot just type that in as the date changes each week.

Any solutions?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** This worksheet is already open.

Comment: Is this file an open workbook?

Comment: If the file is NOT going to be opened when you run that macro/formula, you'll need to include the system path (i.e. C:\User\Files\NSC 06...xlsm)

Comment: maybe you have to include quotation marks at the beginning and at the end, because the filename has space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using the name of the sheet, not the object itself.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & filename & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R8C4:R500C6,3,FALSE)"
```